# How to combine muli or in SQL

Tags: sql

I have this query in my program I want the query ignore if it see the letters
NP or DN but when I wrote this query like this it worked fine but did ignore the letters NP or DN.

How I can let query ignore the letters NP or DN?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(crd) 
FROM 
    courses 
INNER JOIN 
    student_record ON courses.course_number = student_record.course_number 
INNER JOIN 
    grades ON student_record.grade = grades.letter 
           AND (student_record.grade != 'NP' OR student_record.grade != 'DN')
 WHERE 
     student_record.id = 201102887
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT IN`:

```
ON student_record.grade = grades.letter AN
   (student_record.grade NOT IN ('NP' , 'DN')
```

The fix to your logic is to use `AND` rather than `OR`.  Logical operations can get confusing, particularly with negatives.  In this case, I think `NOT IN` is easier to write and to understand.